# How do I recover a password from a custom disk?

Tags: disk-utility, data-recovery

I made a folder with some content into a disk image and assigned it a password. I unfortunately have forgotten the password and cant access it. Any work around solution to the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, No - that's what encryption is for, to prevent anyone getting in who doesn't know the password.